# PostgreSQL - retrieving items in order they were stored

Tags: postgresql

Folks, I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
 userid           CHAR(100)         NOT NULL,
 assetid          text              NOT NULL,
 date             timestamp         NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY(userid, assetid)
);
```

After I run a few insert queries such as :

```
INSERT INTO users (userid, assetid, date) VALUES ( foo, bar, now() );
```

I would like to retrieve records in order they were stored in the database.  However, i seem to be getting back records not in order.

How should I modify my retrieve statement?

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid=foo;
```

I would like the result to be sorted in order things were stored :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your `date` column holds different timestamps for each item, by using the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid=foo ORDER BY "date";
```

However, if you inserted a large number of records in a single transaction, the `date` column value will probably be the same for all of them - if so, there is no way to tell which was inserted first (from the information given).

Answer (score 5):

To expand on Mark's correct answer, PostgreSQL doesn't keep a row timestamp, and it doesn't keep rows in any particular order. Unless you define your tables with a column containing the timestamp they were inserted at, there is no way to select them in the order they were inserted.

PostgreSQL will often return them in the order they were inserted in anyway, but that's just because they happen to be in that order on the disk. This will change as you do `update`s on the table, or `deletes` then later `insert`s. Operations like `vacuum full` also change it. You should never, ever rely on the order without an explicit `order by` clause.

Also, if you want the insertion timestamp to differ for rows within a transaction you can use `clock_timestamp` instead of `now()`. Also, please use the SQL-standard `current_timestamp` instead of writing `now()`.