# Wrong order showing in database data inserted using seeds.exs

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I've used `seeds.exs` to populate with 65 entries my PostgreSQL database with data according to this migration:

```
def change do
  create table(:eventos) do
    add :imgPath, {:array, :string}
    add :youTubePath, {:array, :string}
    add :videoPath, {:array, :string}
    add :date, :string
    add :title, :string
    add :text, :text

    timestamps()
  end
end
```

Assuming I just made a simple `Repo.all(Evento)` in my controller, when seeing my web page I realised that some data was in the wrong position, meaning that it is not appearing in the order it was defined in `seeds.exs`.
When looking directly in the table data using terminal I can see that the order of database `id`s it is following is this:
1,...9,11,15,10,20,30,40,50,60,12,22,32,42,52,62,13,23,...and so on.
I was expecting that data by default is shown according to its database `id.`
1,2,3,...,9,10,11,12,12,14,...

So:

1) Why is this happening
2) how to solve it.

Comment: The rows in a table are ***NOT*** sorted. If you need a specific order, use `order by`

Comment: So, if I want to make sure the `seeds.exs` defined order I must `order_by id` or there is no guarantee either that `seeds.exs` will use that order (top to bottom) to populate DB too?

Comment: The order of inserts is irrelevant. Without an `order by` the database is free to return them in any order it likes. If you need a specific order when you _display_ the data, you **have** to use `order by`.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32699470/330315 or here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7163640/330315

Comment: Yes, but I was assuming that by using Ecto (Elixir specific) it would give me this (`order_by id`) by default (it has being my experience so far with other data, but maybe it's being  just pure chance).

Comment: If you do not use an `order by` then any order you see is pure coincidence

Comment: Got it. I've changed my query and now it's running as expected. If you turn this into an answer I can accept it.